# Combine multiple variables into new variable / Split Variable into 3 variables

Tags: r, variables, split

I need to create a 'key' variable, since I want to combine two datasets.
**Dataset1** has the variable `ymd`.
**Dataset2** has the three variables `y`, `m` and `d`.

```
ymd  (20050516,20060512)  
y(2005,2006)  
m(05,05)
d(16,12)
```

Two Options:

1. Combine y,m and d into variable ymd
2. List item plit variable `ymd` into 3 variables `y`, `m` and `d`.

Comment: Show the code that you have tried

Comment: Add your full code using edit button and add that code into your question

Comment: that is all i have, i am pretty new to R.

Comment: Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve

Comment: As mentioned above, i want to create a key variable that allows me to merge the two datasets. Therefore i need to either combine y,m and d into the variable ymd or split ymd into the three variables y, m and d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ymd = c(20050516,20060512),
  x = c(1,2)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  y = c(2005,2006),  
  m = c('05','05'),
  d = c(16,12),
  z = c(5,10)
)
```

You can merge by pasting together the `y`, `m`, and `d` elements using `paste0` and changing to numeric:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(
    ymd = as.numeric(paste0(y,m,d))
  ) %>%
  left_join(df1)
```

Output:

```
>
Joining, by = "ymd"
     y  m  d  z      ymd x
1 2005 05 16  5 20050516 1
2 2006 05 12 10 20060512 2
```

You can adjust the merge (eg `right_join`) depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you, i have tried this, but i got a mistake. weatherdate <-
  dates%>%
  mutate (
    weatherdata$yearmoda = as.numeric(paste0(dates$year,dates$month,dates$dayofmonth)
  )) %>%
  left_join(weatherdata) Error message is:Error in left_join(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, ...) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
>

Comment: (1) no need for any `$` notation anywhere inside the piping, as everything is flowing from `dataset2`, or `dates` as you call it here.  (2) the `left_join` should reference the other dataset, what you called `dataset1` in the original post.

Comment: Added sample data to clarify. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example.

I use the variables as string instead of numeric, which makes it easier. You can use `as.character()` as in my example to convert it.

For option 1, I just use `paste0()` to paste the text together.

For option 2 I use `substr()` to cut the text in the corect locations.

If you need the output as numeric and not string, just use `as.numeric()` as I did in the print function.

Here is the code, let me know if you have further question:

```
ymd=as.character(c(20050516,20060512))
y=as.character(c(2005,2006))
m=as.character(c(05,05))
d=as.character(c(16,12))

## Concatenade y, m, and d together
ymd_concatenated=paste0(y,m,d)
print(as.numeric(ymd_concatenated))

## Split ymd into single variables
y_concatenated=c()
m_concatenated=c()
d_concatenated=c()
for (date in ymd)
{
  y_concatenated=c(y_concatenated,substr(date,1,4))
  m_concatenated=c(m_concatenated,substr(date,5,6))
  d_concatenated=c(d_concatenated,substr(date,7,8))
}
print(y_concatenated)
print(m_concatenated)
print(d_concatenated)
```